# How can I make sure that I am referencing the correct data type?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

I am trying to create an app where users can select a template on one View, and then edit it in a separate View.
I have two Views and they are both sharing the same data from a Model file. The preview of this second View file is broken and I cannot figure out what the reason is. I know it is a datatype issue.

What I don't understand is why the argument that I pass in isn't in the scope.

I thought that when I was declaring
`@State static var template = Templates.init(backgroundOptions)` I was referencing the Data File or "connecting" my Data File to this View File. Is that not the case?

My "Edit" View looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TemplateEditView: View {
  let template: Templates
 
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      HStack {
        Text("Name: \(template.backgroundOptions.rawValue)") //this should display the title of the image we just clicked on.
          .font(.subheadline)
          .padding()
        Spacer()
      }
        HStack {
          Image("\(template.backgroundOptions.rawValue)") //this needs to be the image we just clicked on.
            .padding()
          Spacer()
        }
      }
    .navigationTitle(template.backgroundOptions.rawValue)
  }
}

struct TemplateEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  @State static var template = Templates.init(backgroundOptions) //1 ERROR: "Cannot find 'backgroundOptions' in scope"
  static var previews: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TemplateEditView(template: Templates.backgroundOptions) //2 ERRORS: "Cannot convert value of type 'Templates.BackgroundOptions' to expected argument type 'Templates'"
"Instance member 'backgroundOptions' cannot be used on type 'Templates'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"
    }
  }
}
```

My Data file looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Template {
    var template: Templates
    
    init(template: Templates) {
      self.template = template 
    }
}

struct Templates {
  var backgroundOptions: BackgroundOptions
      
  enum BackgroundOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case blank = "Blank"
    case fullBorder = "Full Border"
    case laurelWreath = "Laurel Wreath"
    case simpleLine = "Simple Lines"
  }
}
```

My "Select" View file looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TemplatesView: View {
 
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("Choose a Template to Edit").font(.headline)
        List{
            ForEach(Templates.BackgroundOptions.allCases,
                         id: \.self) { backgroundOptions in
                ZStack {
                    Image("\(backgroundOptions)") 
                     .resizable()
                     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   Text(backgroundOptions.rawValue)
                     .font(.title)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        .navigationTitle("Epic Foundries")
    }
  }
}
 

struct TemplatesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TemplatesView()
    }
}
```

My issue is that I am piecing this together from various tutorials from Codecademy. In those tutorials they have code that I don't need. But it seems that when I omit the code I don't need I break the code that I do keep.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't use @State for previews since previews are as the name implies for previewing a view and not for editing data which @State properties are for.

Secondly you need learn how to call an init method, `Templates.init(backgroundOptions)` is wrong in many ways. I can't know for sure what you intended exactly but something like below will work. Notice that the code has a label for the parameter name and a value is passed to it. The `.init` part can be dropped but I leave it for now.

```
Templates.init(backgroundOptions: Templates.BackgroundOptions.blank)
```

Then the next error is a strange mismatch, you need to pass an initial value for the `template` property in the view that is of type `Templates` but instead you pass a value of type `Templates.BackgroundOptions`. I assume you want to use the variable you created earlier so the code should be

```
TemplateEditView(template: template)
```

All in all the preview code would then be

```
struct TemplateEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var template = Templates(backgroundOptions: Templates.BackgroundOptions.blank)
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TemplateEditView(template: template)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I am just now learning to code and I've been using Codecademy. It's my first time branching out into a project of my own so there are many things I don't know or understand in Swift. How come in //TemplateEditView(template: template) the variable references itself? What is the reason for that? Thank you for the help!

Comment: There is no variable referencing itself, the first `template` is a label for the function parameter and the second one the variable. You should really take some time to learn the basics of Swift. [this documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/) is a very good resource and you should definitely read at least the first one third of it.